# Does the new way to use streams (streams2) in node create blocking?

Tags: node.js, stream

I realize that node is non-blocking, however, I also realize that because node has only one thread, putting a three second `while` loop in the middle of your event loop will cause blocking. I.e.:

```
var start = new Date();

console.log('Test 1');

function sleep(time, words) {
    while(new Date().getTime() < start.getTime() + time);
    console.log(words);
}

sleep(3000, 'Test 2'); //This will block

console.log('Test 3') //Logs Test 1, Test 2, Test 3
```

Many of the examples I have seen dealing with the new "Streams2" interface look like they would cause this same blocking. For instance this one, borrowed from [here](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-04-nodejs-readable-streams.html):

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
readStream
  .on('readable', function () {
    var chunk;
    while (null !== (chunk = readStream.read())) {
      hash.update(chunk); //DOESN'T This Cause Blocking?
    }
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
  });
```

If I am following right, the `readStream` will emit the `readable` event when there is data in the buffer.  So it seems that once the `readable` event is emitted, the entire event loop would be stopped until the `readStream.read()` emits null.  This seems less desirable than the old way (because it would not block). Can somebody please tell me why I am wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have to* read until the internal stream buffer is empty. You could just read once if you wanted and then read another chunk some time later.

`readStream.read()` itself is not blocking, but `hash.update(chunk)` is (for a brief amount of time) because the hashing is done on the main thread (there is a github issue about adding an async interface that would execute crypto functions in the thread pool though).

Also, you can simplify the code you have to use the crypto stream interface:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    fs = require('fs');
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt'),
    hasher = crypto.createHash('sha1');

readStream.pipe(hasher).on('readable', function() {
  // the hash stream automatically pushes the digest
  // to the readable side once the writable side is ended
  console.log(this.read());
}).setEncoding('hex');
```

Comment: Doesn't `readStream.pipe(hasher)` return the destination (i.e. `crypto.createHash`) - If this is the case how would the `hasher` object have a `readable` event?  I thought it was the `fs.createReadStream` that is creating the `readable` event?

Comment: The hash stream is a duplex stream, it's readable and writable. The data to be hashed is written to the writable side and the stream pushes the digest to the readable side at the end.

Answer (score 1):

All JS code is single-threaded, so a loop will block, but you are misunderstanding how long that loop will run for. Calling `.read()` takes a readable item from the stream, just like a 'data' handler would be called with the item. It will stop executing and unblock as soon as there are no items. 'readable' is triggered whenever there is data, and then it empties the buffer and waits for another 'readable'. So where your first `while` loop relies on the time to be updated, which could be some unbounded amount of time, the other loop is basically doing:

```
 while (items.length > 0) items.pop()
```

which is pretty much the minimum amount of work you need to do to process items from a stream.

Comment: `while (items.length > 0) items.pop()` does that code <--- block the event loop during it's `pop`ping? In other words, if the stream is very, very long, is everything else blocked?